# Strange screen shaking during scroll in mobile phone viev (video)

Tags: html, css

I have .. strange problem with website background, elements via scrolling in mobile view (Opera browser, Chrome the same):
they are shaking! I didnt know how to describe such problem so made a [video](https://youtu.be/GPAMyWCc3vk)

On mobile phone normal behavie (without shaking), check several different phones.

[Source code](https://shorturl.at/oAEMW)

What is it???
I don't even know the reason.

Comment: Please include a [example].

Comment: I'm sorry but when i created MRE the problem dissapear. I can't to catch it without full code :(
I made a video to demonstrate a problem.

Comment: I just ran your code and used the mobile view and did not experience the issue you have in your video. If I read your post correctly it sounds like the page works on an actual mobile device just fine but the mobile view is where it's shaking? Keep in mind that the browser device viewer is just a _simulator_ and not an actual representation of a live device. For that, you could use https://www.browserstack.com/ Whatever issue your experiencing may be specific to your machine unless anybody else has tried your code and experienced the shaking.

Comment: The video is helpful in displaying the problem, however, it is nearly impossible for us to be able to confidently give you a solution without the problem being replicated. You could try free temporary hosting using [AWS Amplify](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amplify/latest/userguide/welcome.html) or another source.

Comment: Thank you for browserstack.com!
Maybe problem realy only in browser mobile view.